# Excel reading in Delphi 5 with automation and excel 2007 running

Tags: delphi, excel, automation

there was this piece of code in a delphi 5 program that i was debugging:

```
s:string
vararray:variant;

vararray := VarArrayOf(['']);
vararray := ExcelWorkSheet1.UsedRange[0].Value;
s := VarToStr(vararray);
```

This is used to perfectly work when Excel XP and 2003 were running. But ever since I changed to Excel 2007 (also windows7), delphi gives a variant type conversion error on the last line ('Invalid variant type conversion').

Can someone please help me out on this? This code has not been touched for the last 5 years and I am not able to find a good source that documents these components

thanks!

Comment: What does this cell contain? My bet is that it is a date/time held as a string.

Comment: I ask the question because without knowing what this cell contains, it's very hard to answer

Comment: ISTM that on the last-but-one line, vararray is being filled with the values in a range of cells and that there is a difference in how Excel 2003 and 2007 pass an array of values... Go at it with the debugger, check what is in vararray before the call to VarTOStr using both Excel 2003 and 2007. That should give a clue as to why to conversion error is occuring. Could also be related to regional settings wrt to argument separators and a change in behaviour between 2003/2007 in what they use (from where they pick up the separator to use).

Comment: documentation for Office COM servers resided within Office directory tree

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a tiny sample Excel sheet and a tiny Delphi program? Then dump the content of the vararray variable.

Comment: ok will try the debugging. yes i will paste a sample of the excel once i get back to that computer(sorry for not doing so already).

Comment: @david @marjan
hi..
further debugging did not help. I am not able to read the contents of the vararray before conversion
The excel sheet has a normal row of text.
I also observed that when I try to access a particular cell it is fine.
`sTestString := ExcelWorkSheet1.Range[1,1].Value`
works fine, but
`sTestString := ExcelWorkSheet1.Range[1,2].Value`
doesnt

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the following to work:

```
Sheet := Workbook.Sheets.Item[1] as ExcelWorksheet;
value := Sheet.Range['A1','B1'].Value;
Edit1.Text := value[1,1];
Edit2.Text := value[1,2];
```

Note that I am using early binding through the `Excel2000` import unit. I think you are perhaps using late binding with `CreateComObject('Excel.Application')`.

I don't understand your `Range[1,2]` syntax – that doesn't seem to meet the requirements of the Excel object model.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Johan Read the last comment to the question, provided by OP

Comment: `I don't understand your Range[1,2] syntax – that doesn't seem to meet the requirements of the Excel object mode` The [] syntax works with Variants IIRC, the command gets transfered as text to the automation server and Excel VBA does the decoding and gives the result in a Variant, Delphi never even looks at it. I've read about it somewhere in the Delphi 3 manual.

Answer (score 0):

UsedRange need not be active. 
If it isn't the `.value` will be empty and cannot be converted into a string.

Do extra checking, like so:

```
s:string
vararray:variant;

vararray := VarArrayOf(['']);
vararray := ExcelWorkSheet1.UsedRange[0].Value;
if vararray <> nul then s := VarToStr(vararray);
else s := '';
```